# straight line, the question is- Find where the line joining the points $(-3,5)$ and $(-4,8)$ meets the line $x=15$.

Tags: geometry

the question is- Find where the line joining the points $(-3,5)$ 
and $(-4,8)$ meets the line $x=15$ .

all i could do was work out the gradient $-3$ 
please help!!
im not sure how to work this or if i did it right

Comment: Let the point be $(15, y)$. What should the gradient to the point $(-3,5)$ be?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Sandro Lovinički’s first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2888021/265466), the gradient, a.k.a. slope, of the line is $$m = {y_2 - y_1 \over x_2-x_1}.$$ This is an invariant of the line: it is the same no matter which two pairs of points you choose. You therefore have $${8-5 \over (-4)-(-3)} = {y-5 \over 15-(-3)}.$$ Solve for $y$.

This approach essentially uses proportions derived from similar triangles.

Comment: Very concise, but I think the coordinates are not correct. please check (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) substitution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Write the equation of st. line joining the points $(-3,5)$ and $(-4,8)$. Put $x=15$ in the equation. You'll get the value of y-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

#### Gradient approach

What is the meaning of gradient $-3$ you got? Gradient is the slope of the line; it tells us for how many units $y$ changes (in your case drops by $3$) when $x$ increases by $1$. Only from this you can conclude what $y$ will be when $x$ is $15$ (when it "meets the line $x=15$") because you know what $y$ was at $x$ values of $-3$ and $-4$ (only one is enough for this deduction).

#### "Standard approach"

First we need to find the line equation connecting points $(x_1,y_1)=(-3,5)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(-4,8)$. We know that a basic form of a line equation is
\begin{equation}
y = a \cdot x + b
\end{equation}
where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ are values we need to find out. We are looking for a line on which both of our points are, so we want our two points' $x$ and $y$ coordinates satisfy the above general line equation. If we write that which we just stated (what we want), we get
\begin{align*}
y_1 &= a \cdot x_1 + b\\
y_2 &= a \cdot x_2 + b
\end{align*}
where only $a,b$ are unknowns when we input our values of $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$. You should try to solve this yourself.
When you get the solution, i.e values for $a$ and $b$, pluck them into $y=a \cdot x + b$ and that is the equation of a line passing through your $2$ points.

The the task directs you to find the intersection of that line and line $x=15$ which maybe seems confusing because it is not of the form $y=ax+b$. It just mean that there is no relationship between $x$ and $y$, that $x$ is always $15$ and $y$ is arbitrary. You can visualize or draw that; it is the line that is parallel to the $y$-axis and passes through $15$ at $x$-axis.

To find an intersection of two lines
\begin{align*}
y &= a_1 \cdot x + b_1\\
y &= a_2 \cdot x + b_2,
\end{align*}
means that we have to find a point $(x_0,y_0)$ that satisfies both of them because that point is the only point **on both** of the lines. Generally, to find an intersection, we solve the above system of equations, but in our case it is a simpler system because we have
\begin{align*}
y &= a \cdot x + b \quad \text{(line through your two points in the task)}\\
x &= 15 \quad \text{(second line)},
\end{align*}
Therefore, we know that the intersection $(x_0,y_0)$ we are looking for will have $x_0 = 15$ (remember, the intersection must satisfy both line equations, so to satisfy the second one it must have 15 on $x$-coordinate). Now when we know $x_0$, we calculate $y_0$ using the first equation
\begin{equation}
y_0 = a \cdot 15 + b
\end{equation}
and because you already know $a,b$ from one of the first steps I explained (finding line equation passing through your two points), you directly calculate $y_0$.

There, you have your solution $(x_0,y_0)$. Feel free to share what you got in the comments.

Comment: I would emphasize your first approach, which doesn’t require forming the equation of the line. Effectively, it uses similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Note: for advanced discussion of this, please refer to: [Wiki-Line–line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection).

When $2$ lines intersect, the point of intersection satisfies the equation of each of the intersecting lines. In your case, you have one equation fully written as $x=15$. However the other equation is not known.

You want to find the equation for a line that passes through the two points:

$(-3,5) and (-4,8)$.

it is common to work with points using (x,y) coordinates. So we have:

point 1 having $(x1,y1)$ as $(-3,5) ==> x1=-3$ and $y1=5$
similarly for point 2, we have $x2=-4$ and $y2=8$

The line equation can be written in this form:
$y = mx+b$ Where:

m is the slope value, and

b is the y-intercept value

The slope of the above line, given $2$ points can be calculated as:
$m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)$

given the $2$ points we have, m can be found as:

m=$(8-5)/(-4-(-3))=3/-1=-3$

So, the line equation is now:

$y=-3x+b$

But b is not known yet. We can find b by using the values from any of the given points. Lets use the value of point $1$, we know that when $x=-3$, $y=5$ because the point $1$ has the coordinates $(-3,5)$. This means that when we substitute the values in the above equation we get:

$5=-3(-3)+b$

From the above we can determine $b=5-9=-4$

Now we can write the complete line equation after we have determined m and b as:

$y=-3x+(-4)==> y=-3x-4$

When two lines intersect the x value will be the same on each line.
We need to re-write the above equation in terms of $x=...$ so we can use this fact.

$y=-3x-4 ==> y+4=-3x ==> x= (y+4)/(-3)$

At the intersection point the x-values are the same, so:

$(x=15)=(y+4)/-3$

That is:

$(15)*(-3)=y+4 ==> y=(15*-3)-4 =-49 ==> y=-49$

Since the 2 lines intersect, the x-values and y-values are the same for both lines. We have determined that $y=-49$ and we were given that $x=15$, so the point (15,-49) is the point of intersection of the 2 lines.

Note that this point, satisfies the equation $x=15$ and also satisfies the line equation we have constructed $y=-3x-4$ which you can test by substituting x=15 to get y=-49 as expected.

To verify the answer, it is sometimes possible to plot the two lines as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without explaining why, I present the following steps:

1. Line connecting the two points $[-3,5]$ and $[-4,8]$ is described in terms of $ax+by+c=0$ coordinates $(a,b,c)$ as

   $$ \pmatrix{a \\ b \\ c} = \left[ \matrix{-3 \\ 5 \\ 1} \right] \times \left[ \matrix{-4 \\ 8 \\ 1} \right] = \pmatrix{-3 \\ -1 \\ -4} $$
2. Line described by $x=15$ seen as connecting two points $[15,0]$ and $[15,1]$ with $(a',b',c')$ coordinates

   $$ \pmatrix{a' \\b' \\c'} = \left[ \matrix{15 \\ 0 \\ 1} \right] \times \left[ \matrix{15 \\ 1 \\ 1} \right] = \pmatrix{-1 \\ 0 \\ 15} $$
3. Point joining the two lines in homogeneous coordinates $(x \,w, y \,w, w)$

   $$ \left[ \matrix{x\,w \\ y \,w \\ w} \right] = \pmatrix{-1 \\ 0 \\ 15} \times \pmatrix{-3 \\ -1 \\ -4} = \left[ \matrix{15 \\ -49 \\ 1} \right] $$ The joining point has cordinates $x=\frac{15}{1} = 15$ and $y=\frac{-49}{1}=-49$.

<sub>NOTE: $\times$ here is the vector cross product.</sub>